# Слива, сливки и сливать

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Понятно, что слово "сливки" произошло от глагола "сливать": их сливают с молока, потому что они всегда на поверхности. А вот каким образом родственен словам "сливки" и "сливать" фрукт слива? Честно говоря, я даже представить себе не могу, что такого можно сделать с этим фруктом, чтобы увязать его с глаголом "сливать" или с молочными сливками?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему у этих слов общий корень "слив"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Накопал". Слово "слива", скорее всего, искажено от латинского "livor" - "синий". И к "сливкам" отношения не имеет. Скорее - к "Ливии".

Comment: Синие ливки )))

Answer (score 0):

У сливок "с" – это исторически приставка. А корень "ли". Сравните: лить, сливать.

Answer (score 0):

Слива - в др.-рус. языке отмечается с 12 века, о.-с. основа sliva, и.-е корень sliuo, дерево названо по цвету плодов.